# install_github(): "system error 267, The directory name is invalid"

Tags: r, github, devtools, install.packages, remotes

I am trying to install package `performance` development version with `devtools` but am getting this error:

```
> devtools::install_github("easystats/performance")
Downloading GitHub repo easystats/performance@HEAD
Error: Failed to install 'performance' from GitHub:
  create process 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe' (system error 267, The directory name is invalid.
) @win/processx.c:1040 (processx_exec)
```

Same thing with alternative `remotes` command:

```
> remotes::install_github("easystats/performance")
Downloading GitHub repo easystats/performance@HEAD
Error: Failed to install 'performance' from GitHub:
  create process 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe' (system error 267, The directory name is invalid.
) @win/processx.c:1040 (processx_exec)
```

*Edit: Note that I am getting the same error no matter what package I've tried to install through `devtools` (e.g., `cardiomoon/processR` or `r-lib/crayon`). This started to happen suddenly a few weeks ago yet never had this issue before. So it seems not related to the package but to something else.*

So I tried changing my default library to the simplest ever location that doesn't have any special characters or require any admin rights, with those [instructions](https://code.adonline.id.au/changing-the-default-library-folder-path-in-r/). I can confirm that `C:/Rpackages` is now indeed my default library path, and that it is first (on the left):

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Rpackages"                      "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library"
```

However, I am still getting the same error. The weird thing is that the error still seems to refer to the second library path rather than the first one, which seems off to me. From the help documentation, I don't see how to specify the library location explicitly for neither `devtools` nor `remotes`. Also interesting, notice that the error seems to mention `R-40~1.3` instead of `R-4.0.3` as it should(?). Might this be the issue? Then how to fix?

I also tried reinstalling `devtools` and `remotes`, to no avail.

Yet, it works if I install the regular CRAN version:

```
> install.packages("performance")
Installing package into ‘C:/Rpackages’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/performance_0.7.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2487172 bytes (2.4 MB)
downloaded 2.4 MB

package ‘performance’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

Here my session info if useful:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3    yaml_2.2.1
```

Comment: "So I tried changing my default library to the simplest ever location that doesn't have any special characters" space is a special character

Comment: Good point @Hong Ooi ... but "C:/Program Files" is as well and normally spaces don't produce errors when installing packages? That being said, I tried removing the space and same error :P Edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Does this only happen with the `performance` package or do other packages from github install without an error?  You also try to force the library location like this: `remotes::install_github("easystats/performance", lib = "C:/Rpackages")`.

Comment: Good point @Till! I am also experiencing the same issue trying to install `cardiomoon/processR` and `r-lib/crayon`. This started to happen suddenly a few weeks ago yet never had this issue before. So it seems not related to the package but to something else. I have edited my question to reflect this better. Yet, I've tried reinstalling `devtools` and `remotes`. Would you suggest attempting to reinstall Rstudio or R then?

Comment: @Till forgot to mention that even when specify `lib` I'm still getting the error. I'm starting to think that it might not be related to the location of the library but to some sort of Windows process. Indeed, I ended up reinstalling Rtools, R, and Rstudio, and still experiencing this error. So at this point I wonder if it is not more of a Windows problem (e.g., with Environment variables?).

Comment: Hi, I had the same error. I just gonna link the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400661/r-unable-to-install-packages-from-github-system-error-267-win-processx-c1040/68408378#68408378): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400661/r-unable-to-install-packages-from-github-system-error-267-win-processx-c1040/68408378#68408378

for other people searching for this. In the hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the `processx` package and the development version has since received a fix (in version `v3.5.3`). Please see the following discussion for more info: https://github.com/r-lib/processx/issues/313