# R Unable to Install Packages From GitHub (System Error 267 @win/processx.c:1040)

Tags: r, github, devtools

#### TL;DR

> Unable to install **any** package from GitHub, System Error 267

I've newly setup R (v4.1), Rstudio and just installed devtools.
I also additionally installed [Rtools40](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and added it to my path (global environment)

Rtools seems to work properly as validated with: `Sys.which("make")` & `maketools::rtools_find()` (output below)

## Problem

I am unable to install **any** package from GitHub, e.g. [rstudio/gt](https://github.com/rstudio/gt). The error is nearly identical for any GitHub Package, allways stating `system error 267`

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt")
Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/gt@HEAD
Error: Failed to install 'gt' from GitHub:
  create process 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe' (system error 267, Der Verzeichnisname ist ungültig.
) @win/processx.c:1040 (processx_exec
```

#### Update

As suggested I reinstalled R 4.1.0 to the most simple folde possible `C:/R/`
The error ist still the same despite now lacking tildes `~`

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt")
Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/gt@HEAD
Error: Failed to install 'gt' from GitHub:
  create process 'C:/R/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe' (system error 267, Der Verzeichnisname ist ungültig.
) @win/processx.c:1040 (processx_exec)
```

#### Update 2:

Changed the .libPaths to a folder without any special characters

```
.libPaths( c( "D:/tmp" , .libPaths() ) )
.libPaths()
[1] "D:/tmp"                                     "C:/Users/Björn/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"
[3] "C:/R/library"  

Error is still the same
```

#### Update 3:

I updated some packages, and checked the version of `packageVersion('processx')`= 3.5.2

```
install.packages("testthat") 
install.packages("pkgload") 
install.packages("devtools") 
install.packages("remote")
```

Content of Sys.getenv

```
 Sys.getenv('Path')
[1] "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin;C:\\R\\bin\\x64;C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin;C:\\rtools40\\mingw64\\bin;
```

## Diagnostics

#### Session Info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

#### Rtools successful installed / setup

```
Sys.which("make")
                              make 
"C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe" 

maketools::rtools_find()
$version
[1] ‘4.0’

$compiler
[1] "gcc 8.3.0"

$api
[1] ‘8’

$PATH
[1] "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin"

$BINPREF
[1] "C:/rtools40/mingw$(WIN)/bin/"

$available
[1] TRUE

$compatible
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Related: https://community.rstudio.com/t/install-github-system-error-267-the-directory-name-is-invalid/107145. It might be related to why the [R for Windows FAQ 2.2](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f) recommends against installing in a path that contains a space. (I've always been confused why they have this recommendation but the installer *defaults* to `C:\Program Files\R\`, perhaps it's the msi and environment variables at play, but still ...)

Comment: If you have the ability, try uninstalling R then reinstalling it in (say) `C:/R/` (instead of its default, `C:/Program Files/R/`).

Comment: How did you install R? Did you use the standard R installer?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-the-directory-name-is-invalid-error-message-when-you-start-cmd-exe-or-notepad-exe-by-using-the-run-as-feature-in-windows-bdf64686-ab07-a60d-f2b2-1c6cb34e2992

Comment: Also [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67975277/error-windows-cant-find-c-progra1-check-the-spelling-and-try-again), however sadly unsolved. Yes sure I can reinstall R into C:/R/ will do this and report the result. @r2evans yes I used this standard [installer](https://cran.r-project.org/) from cran

Comment: @r2evans updated my answer, change in the installation dir of R didn't help

Comment: Where is the package being installed? (`.libPaths()`). If that is a network drive or a onedrive-like directory (which has caused problems in the past), then perhaps this is a bug-report for `remotes` (since `devtools` just re-exports `remotes::install_github`).

Comment: No its not a network drive it's local, output of `.libPaths()` : `[1] "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"
[2] "C:/R/library"` Hmm what kind of wonders me is the output of `maketools::rtools_find()`, as the `$PATH` uses the double backslash notation (escaping one) however `$BINREF` uses the normal forward slash notation. Could that be the root?

Comment: I don't think so: R on windows accepts either `C:\\...` or `C:/...`; it even accepts them interchangeably, so `C:\\Users/xxx\\Documents` will do what one might hope. (I personally find this to be a small breath of sanity, double-backslashes really irritate my eyes :-)

Comment: Doubt it's the slashes.  Does your user name (in your libpath) have include ö (like your username)? Can you create a temporary folder without any special characters and see if it'll install in there with something like `devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt", lib = "d:/tmp/rlib")`

Comment: Thanks both of you. I created the directory `D:/tmp` and tried your command `devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt", lib = "D:/tmp")` however lib seems to be an unkown parameter to [install_github](https://rdrr.io/cran/remotes/man/install_github.html). However I wrote an update to the OP. I tried to change D:/tmp to the first directory in .libsPath(). The error remains the same :(. At this point I am getting really desperate

Comment: Weird - I tested before I posted.  I must have screwed up, sorry (I assumed the `lib` argument would be passed to `install.packages` via `...`, but I guess not).  So there are no special characters left anywhere in your `.libPaths()`?  How about in `Sys.getenv('PATH')`?  Clutching at straws, but the error implies it's not handling a directory name _somewhere_.  Do you have the latest version of the `processx` package (`packageVersion('processx')` should be 3.5.2)?

Comment: Just noticed your update 2.  Any difference if you get rid of the `"C:/Users/Björn/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"` entry altogether, instead of just prepending `D:/tmp`?  i.e. just `.libPaths( "D:/tmp" )`.  I am assuming you've created `d:\tmp`, of course

Comment: Yes tried removing everything else from `.libPaths()` aswell. Did take forever for stingi to be compiled. However, error for installing the package from github remains the same. Trying the updare of processx now und will post `Sys.getenv` as update to the post

Comment: I also tried to leave Rstudio out of the equation and ran the install_github directly from the R console. However what really wonders me was, despite being in the `Sys.getenv('Path')` (see the update to the post), I was not able to start R from the command line. Typing `R` in the command line, it says me `Command R is either written wrong or could not be found`

Comment: I think you'll be better off filing a bug report at [the repo](https://github.com/r-lib/processx) instead of going around in circles here

Comment: Also, on Windows, R is not on the search path by default

Comment: Thanks @HongOoi I did. You can find it [here](https://github.com/r-lib/processx/issues/313). If I manage to solve it, I will update here as well, so that in the future people maybe able to find the right solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standalone mode of the remotes package solved the issue for me,
as suggested by the maintainer of [processx](https://github.com/r-lib/processx) (Gábor Csárdi) [here](https://github.com/r-lib/processx/issues/313)

`devtools::install_github()` only calls `remotes::install_github()`.
However, for the remotes, there is the option to be exectued in standalone mode

**Source: [Cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/remotes/readme/README.html)**

> Standalone mode
>
> remotes will use the curl, git2r and pkgbuild packages if they are
> installed to provide faster implementations for some aspects of the
> install process. However if you are using remotes to install or update
> these packages (or their reverse dependencies) using them during
> installation may fail (particularly on Windows).
>
> If you set the environment variable R_REMOTES_STANDALONE="true" (e.g.
> in R Sys.setenv(R_REMOTES_STANDALONE="true")) you can force remotes to
> operate in standalone mode and use only its internal R
> implementations. This will allow successful installation of these
> packages

With the following lines of code, gt was finally successfull installed from github.

```
Sys.setenv(R_REMOTES_STANDALONE="true")
remotes::install_github("rstudio/gt")
```

Thanks all the commentators for your help!

#### Update October / 2021

To avoid having to do these steps (Set in standanlone mode, and install with remotes) over and over again everytime you want to install a new package from github another convenient workaround is to just rollback to the previous version of `processx` as adviced by @rempsy in the github issue:

```
install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_del(processx)
# Installing previous verison 3.5.1
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/processx/processx_3.5.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

After the rollback of processx to `version 3.5.1`, `devtools::install_github()` works as expected, e.g.

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt")
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I tested it and can confirm it works. It's a shame that we have to use a workaround like this though, I hope someone else will be able to get at the bottom of this issue to fix the problem for the many more users who experience this problem but that will not stumble upon this workaround.